# MonoDevelop not working on Leopard 10.5.5

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop, xamarin

I downloaded the Mono Develop package (http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Mac/XamarinStudio-4.0.12-3.dmg) for Mac.But after unpacking the package and clicking on the Xamarin(Mono Develop Icon),Mac says this version is not compatible.Can you tell me where to find a compatible version or which version supports the OS(Leopard 10.5.5) when it comes to Mac,im a complete Noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leopard is six years old - released in October 2007.  I wouldn't expect many companies to still actively support it.

From the [Xamarin docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/installation):

> To create Mac applications using Xamarin.Mac, you need to have an
>   Apple Macintosh computer running at least Lion (OS X 10.7). If you
>   want to distribute your applications, either in the Apple App Store or
>   by giving out application files, you also need to have an active
>   membership in the Apple Developer Program, which costs $99USD/year.
>
> Before you install Xamarin.Mac, you need to download and install the
>   latest Xcode from the Apple website.

Comment: Okay.But do I need the developer account if I plan to offer downloads from my website or other distribution site's rather than Mac store

Comment: I *think* that you need the developer account if you want to sign your apps (which is required for App store distribution).  If you want to distribute without signing, you're ok.  But some users may not be able to install unsigned apps.

Comment: Users on Mac OS X 10.8 and later will only be abled to install signed packages by default. They can disable the security check, but that will likely make many users nervous.

Comment: @jstedfast How is the process of disabling security check? Is it complicated or a few clicks.Also am i allowed to create packages without a developer account?

Comment: I think they have to go into their System Preferences -> Security. It's probably just "uncheck this checkbox" thing. Honestly, I forget the exact steps, but it's something along those lines. I think you can write Mac apps w/o an Apple Developer account (and if you use MonoMac, you don't need a Xamarin Developer Account either).